# jQuery Overlay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

My jQuery overlay is this

```
$(function() {
    $("#triggers a[rel]").overlay({
        top: '24%',
        effect: 'apple',
        fixed: false,
        mask: {
            color: '#0f0f0f',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.9
        },
        closeOnClick: false
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(div.contentWrap);
        }

    });
});
```

and my HTML code is this

```
   <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay1">
     <div class="contentWrap">

       <div class="video-js-box">
         <video class="video-js" height="191px" width="246px" controls="controls" 
              preload="auto" poster="url">
            <source src="url" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
         </video>
         </div>

       </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is, video player(videoJS) loaded behind overlay. How to Wrap this video player into the overlay. I think there is problem with onBeforeLoad: in jQuery please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give video video-js-box class a high z-index, 99999999 for an example and see if that works.